# Passing information form HTML to TS using generated checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, frontend

having an issue with my Angular project. Basically, I have a mat-table with 15 rows that contains some data. I added checkboxes at the end of the row so that when the checkbox is clicked, and then a button is pressed, it manipulates the data by calling an API (I will call the API once I figure out how to pass it the appropriate data)

[Looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trsMa.png)

The table data is generated like this:

**HTML**

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource$">
     <ng-container matColumnDef="process">
        <mat-header-cell #checkBox *matHeaderCellDef> Process </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let execution"> {{execution.process}} </mat-cell>
     </ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="reprocess">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>  
         <button tslbutton class="tslbutton" (click)="reprocessHomeProcesses(checkBox)" id="reprocessButton">
            Reprocess
         </button> 
      </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell id="reprocessCell" *matCellDef="let execution">
         <mat-checkbox class="checker" #checkBox></mat-checkbox>
      </mat-cell>
   </ng-container>
<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
     <mat-row #checkBox *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
```

**TS**

```
dataSource$ = new MatTableDataSource();

//on page load dataSource$ is populated with 15 objects. These are different each time

reprocessHomeProcesses(checkboxes) {
    console.log(checkboxes))
  }
```

I'm unable to access the data stored in "execution". In HTML I can view it by something like this:

```
<span>{{execution.process}}</span>
```

this returns the process field of the execution object.

but I cannot pass this data to the TS. I tried using #checkBox and passing that as an argument to reprocessHomeProcesses() but this returns undefined. Is there an easier solution to

1. determine which checkboxes have been selected
2. pass the data from execution into TS based on the selected checkboxes?

All of the information that I need is in the execution variable. Basically, when the box is checked and the button is pressed, I need the execution data sent back to the TypeScript. But when I try to pass execution as the argument to my reprocessHomeProcesses() it returns as undefined, even though execution has the data that is creating the rows. Why is this happening?

Is it not possible to send execution from HTML to TS using the checkbox? I have had no luck in many hours.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is in `execution`? Can't you store it on the window object so all scripts on the page can then have access to it? e.g. `<script>window.execution = ...</script>`

Comment: Execution is an object. It holds the data for the rest of the columns. The other columns are populated like `<mat-cell>{{execution.id}}</mat-cell>`. How would I go about storing it in the window? I'm not sure if this can be done for this project

Answer (score 0):

In Angular *(React, and VueJs)* you not query the DOM direct with `document.querySelector(...)` *(or similars)*.

These frameworks are data centered, what you need is define a public variable in your Controller to hold the data, and that variable will be updated by the `2-way data binding` of Angular:

In the Template *(HTML)*:

```html
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource$">
     <ng-container matColumnDef="process">
        <mat-header-cell #checkBox *matHeaderCellDef> Process </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let execution"> {{execution.process}} </mat-cell>
     </ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="reprocess">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>  
         <button tslbutton class="tslbutton" (click)="reprocessHomeProcesses()" id="reprocessButton">
            Reprocess
         </button> 
      </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell id="reprocessCell" *matCellDef="let execution; let i = index">
         <mat-checkbox class="checker" [(ngModel)]="auxiliarDataSource[i].checked"></mat-checkbox>
      </mat-cell>
   </ng-container>
<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
     <mat-row #checkBox *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
```

*Remove the parameter from "reprocessHomeProcesses", and put `[(ngModel)]="execution.checked"` on the "mat-checkbox"*

In the Controller *(TS)*, something like:

```js
export class MyController {
  dataSource: [
    { process: 1 },
    { process: 2 },
  ];
  auxiliarDataSource: [
    { checked: false, index: 0 },
    { checked: false, index: 1 },
  ];

  void reprocessHomeProcesses() {
    let filteredIndex = this.auxiliarDataSource.filter(x => x.checked).map( x => x.index );
    let filteredItens = this.dataSource.filter( (x,i)=> filteredIndex.indexOf(i) )
    console.log( filteredItens );
  }

  // ... more code ahead
}
```

***Code Not Tested***

Comment: What exactly is checksData? I need to return my execution object

Comment: your "execution" object is the "checksData" (somehow), but it need to be a list, with one object for each checkbox.

Comment: Execution is an array of data. It populates the rest of the table with data. I need that. When a row's checkbox is selected I need the execution data that filled the rest of that row to be passed back to the TS. Right now it goes as undefined, but when I literally display it on the screen in HTML it shows me it's there.

Comment: so, maybe using something like "execution.check" on [(ngModel)]="execution.check" will work? Can test for us? Also, you can call "reprocessHomeProcesses( execution )". But now i'm a little confuse on how you create the table, how is the structure of "execution", can update with the TS code for us to understand?

Comment: I updated with some code. It's just an array of 15 objects. It does not have a field called check

Comment: Maybe i start to understand, i made some few changes on what you post now. Now i beleave the logs will show it updated when you check one and click the button

Comment: console.log(this.dataSource$) is just returning every item in dataSource$ not just the checked ones

Comment: Yes, this is espected, but if you can filter the checkeds with: this.dataSource.filter(x => x.checked);  i updated with this piece too

Comment: I'm not sure if I've done something wrong, but I get an error when I try to add that filtering. "Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'unknown'. When I try and just print the entire array, I don't see checked as a field type. Was this added?

Comment: you need to add this field before, when you get / fetch your data, you add this field (on load, or the contructor, initialization, where you get the data, walk throght the data and add this field with "false" value)

Comment: Is it possible to do this without changing the structure of the dataSource$ ? dataSource$ is populated through API and is used in other locations than just here.

Comment: I don't see an easy way to alter it's structure.

Comment: i added an auxiliar list, and `*matCellDef="let execution; let i = index"` on the checkbox part too. This way can work for u?

Comment: I don't understand what auxiliar list does. Also since data is generated through API there is no limit to the number of objects. Auxilier only has 2 which couldn't work

Comment: Is there no simple way to send execution to the TS without adding new lists and new fields?

Comment: on the constructor you can put one item inside `auxiliarDataSource` for each item on the `dataSource`, this way they will have the same size (length)

Comment: There are over 100,000 items in dataSource. I have it formatting to only 15 per page.